# Reading in numpy array from buffer with different data types without copying array

Tags: python, numpy

I have data encoded as a binary string, with a mix of data types.

As an example (real data is much larger),

```
data = b'l:\x00\x00\xc0\xff|:g\x8em\xbf}:\xceUq\xbf'
```

I am reading this into an numpy array:

```
buffer = np.frombuffer(np.array(data), dtype='B')
```

which gives

```
array([108,  58,   0,   0, 192, 255, 124,  58, 103, 142, 109, 191, 125,
    58, 206,  85, 113, 191], dtype=uint8)
```

I need to change this to `(np.uint16, np.float)`, so the above array is

```
[(14956,NaN),(14972,-0.9280),(14973,-0.9427)]
```

I can use view for a single data type, e.g.
    `buffer.view(dtype=np.uint16)`  gives

```
array([14956,     0, 65472, 14972, 36455, 49005, 14973, 21966, 49009], dtype=uint16)
```

However don't think I can use a combination of data types for view like this. I have tried reshaping and slicing this,

```
buffer = buffer.reshape((3,-1))
firstData = buffer[:,:2]
firstData = array([[108,  58],
                   [124,  58],
                   [125,  58]], dtype=uint8)
firstData.view(dtype = np.uint16)
ValueError: new type not compatible with array.
```

As hinted in the documentation, this can be resolved by copying

```
firstData = firstData.copy()
firstData.view(dtype=np.uint16)
array([[14956],
       [14972],
       [14973]], dtype=uint16)
```

Is there a fast way to do this without copying the array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a structured data type with two fields:

```
In [89]: data = b'l:\x00\x00\xc0\xff|:g\x8em\xbf}:\xceUq\xbf'

In [90]: dt = np.dtype([('a', np.uint16), ('b', np.float32)])

In [91]: x = np.frombuffer(data, dtype=dt)

In [92]: x
Out[92]: 
array([(14956,         nan), (14972, -0.92795414), (14973, -0.94271553)], 
      dtype=[('a', '<u2'), ('b', '<f4')])
```

`x` is a one-dimensional [structured array](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.rec.html); each item in `x` is a structure with fields `a` and `b`:

```
In [93]: x[0]
Out[93]: (14956,  nan)

In [94]: x['a']
Out[94]: array([14956, 14972, 14973], dtype=uint16)
```

Note that I used `np.float32` for the floating point field.  `np.float` was an alias for the Python builtin `float`.  It was deprecated for a long time, and has been removed from recent versions of numpy.